# script show errors about design

Tags: php, html

i tested a script like 5months ago it was all good, when i uploaded now it on a host it shows so much errors any idea what is the problem ?

It shows like this: https://prnt.sc/118djwo , https://prnt.sc/118dkmy

So it dont show the design like navbar, butons etc it shows only text typed

the code of this page:

```
 <?php
include "config.php";
include "functions/function.views.php";
include "functions/function.notifications.php";
if(!isset($_SESSION['aname']) and !isset($_SESSION['apass'])){
     header("location: login.php");
     exit();
}
function extrat_ress($item,$query, $dbcon){
        $line1 = mysqli_query($dbcon,$query);
        $line2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($line1);
        return $line2[$item];
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
        <title>TEST</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            .loader {
                position: fixed;
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                z-index: 9999;
                background: url('https://vanishingpointcreative.com/bhiva/app/assets/preloader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
            }
        .well-box.linnea {
                line-height: 25px;
        }
        .rad-info-box {
                border-radius:13px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0 #CCCCCC;
            padding: 20px;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.16),0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
            background: white !important;}
        .rad-info-box i {
            display: block;
            background-clip: padding-box;
            margin-right: 15px;
            height: 60px;
            width: 60px;
            border-radius: 100%;
            line-height: 60px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 4.4em;
            position: absolute;
        }
        .rad-info-box .value,
        .rad-info-box .heading {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            color: #515d6e;
            text-align: right;
            z-index: 10;
        }
        .rad-info-box .heading {
            font-size: 1.2em;
            font-weight: 300;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        .rad-info-box .value {
            font-size: 2.1em;
            font-weight: 600;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
            .rad-info-box i {
                opacity: .3;
            }
        }
        </style>
        <!-- jquery -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Notifer Alert -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap252.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" >

        <!-- Custom core CSS -->
        <link href="css/stylea.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/navbarr.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
        <link href="css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="css/offcanvas.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- datatable information -->
        <link href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- SweetAlert -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="alerts/sweetalert.css">
        <script src="alerts/sweetalert-dev.js"></script>
        <script src="alerts/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

        <!-- spin files -->
        <script src="js/spin.js"></script>
        <script src="js/spin.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/alertify.core.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/alertify.default.css" />
        <script src="js/alertify.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body style="margin-top: 75px;">
        <!-- // loader -->
        <div class="loader"></div>

        <!-- // nav menu -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">TEST</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="Dashboard" style="margin-left: 10px;">TEST</a>
                </div>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="border-radius: 0;">

                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header" style="margin-left: 15px;">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">TEST</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="Dashboard">TEST</a>
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">

                    <!-- //left menu -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>
                            <a>||</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="A"></i>A</a></li>  
                    
                        <li><a href="S"></i>S</a></li>
    
                        <li><a href="T"></i>T</a></li>

                        



                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Balance&nbsp;<b>
                                <?php
                                    $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon,$_SESSION['aname']);
                                    echo '<span class="label btn-info">'.
                                    extrat_ress('balance',"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$uid."'",$dbcon).
                                    '$</b></span>';
                                ?>
                                <b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="btc.php"><i class="fa fa-btc"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add Bitcoin$</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pm.php"><i class="fa fa-rub"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add PerfectMoney$</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="Dashboard-billing"><i class="fa fa-history"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Billing History</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Support&nbsp;<b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="Dashboard-tickets"><i class="fa fa-commenting"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;My Tickets</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Dashboard-reports"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Reported</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="newticket.php"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Open New Ticket</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                                    <li><a href="Dashboard-purchased-tools"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Purchased </a></li>

                        <li><a href="Rules"></i>Rules</a></li>                      
                        <li><a href="Active"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-up"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>

                    </ul>

                    <!-- // reight menu -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-right : 5px;">
            =
                                <li><a href="Dashboard-password"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;My Profile</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                </li><li><a href="logout.php"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </nav>
        </nav>


        <?php
        $q=mysqli_query($dbcon,"SELECT * FROM s WHERE sold='0'");
        $q0=mysqli_query($dbcon,"SELECT * FROM c WHERE sold='0'");
        $q1=mysqli_query($dbcon,"SELECT * FROM a WHERE sold='0'");
        $q2=mysqli_query($dbcon,"SELECT * FROM t WHERE sold='0'");
        $q3=mysqli_query($dbcon,"SELECT * FROM tool ");
        $wsq = mysqli_query($dbcon,"SELECT * FROM settings")or die(mysqli_error());
        $rsq = mysqli_fetch_assoc($wsq);
        // check if banned
        $user = $_SESSION['aname'];
        $sbanned = mysqli_query($dbcon,"SELECT * FROM banned WHERE username='$user'") or die(mysqli_error());
        $nbanned = mysqli_num_rows($sbanned);
        if($nbanned > 0)
        {
            header("Location: banned.html");
            die();
            exit();
        }
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function buythistool(id){
                var tbl = $("#buyt"+id).attr('type');
                    $.ajax({
                     method:"GET",
                     url:"ajax/buytool.php?id="+id+"&t="+tbl,
                     dataType:"text",
                     success:function(data){
                             if(data.match(/successfully/)){
                                     sweetAlert("",data,"success")
                             }else{
                                    sweetAlert("",data,"error")
                             }
                     },
                 });
            }
            function check(id){
                var type = $("#shop"+id).attr('type')
                $("#shop"+id).html('<img src="w1loading.gif" alt="Wait">').show();
                $.ajax({
                type:       'GET',
                url:        'checker.php?id='+id+'&type='+type,
                success:    function(data)
                {
                    $("#shop"+id).html(data).show();
                }});
            }
            function cpanelit(id){
                $("#shop"+id).html('<img src="img/w1loading.gif" alt="Wait">').show();
                $.ajax({
                type:       'GET',
                url:        'cpanel.php?id='+id,
                success:    function(data)
                {
                    $("#shop"+id).html(data).show();
                }});
            }
            $(window).load(function() {
                $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
            })
        </script>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in the browser console(f12). Looks like the css might not be loading.

Comment: You have an error. [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) needs one argument. Please consider switching error mode on instead. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: i just checked it and it shows thos errors: https://prnt.sc/118e7yv

Answer (score 0):

Your issue in style paths, you set static path for heads file...

Simply, try to add backslash for your includes like:
"/css/..."
or
"/js/..."

```
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Notifer Alert -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="/css/bootstrap252.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome.min.css" >

    <!-- Custom core CSS -->
    <link href="/css/stylea.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/navbarr.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="/css/offcanvas.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- datatable information -->
    <link href="/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- SweetAlert -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="alerts/sweetalert.css">
    <script src="alerts/sweetalert-dev.js"></script>
    <script src="alerts/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

    <!-- spin files -->
    <script src="/js/spin.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/spin.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/alertify.core.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/alertify.default.css" />
    <script src="/js/alertify.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
```

================

For trace issue, you can open console and check errors, if this solution not resolve your issue, you can take screen shoot from console error and check network error file...any 404 or 401

also make sure your read/write file is set correctly in host like
644 for file, 755 for directory.

Comment: I checked the errors from console and it shows those errors: https://prnt.sc/118e7yv

Comment: this is another issue!, Your issue is too many redirect, I think you are add condition in to redirect you to login, and this condition is work in login too, so that you redirect to login and login redirect again to login and so on....